# Nsarray summary unavailable (EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, nsarray, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to make a game, which use animations (of UIImages), but i have a really unuasal (for me) bug :
I tried to animate an image when occured an intersection between two CGRects. The detection is great, but the behaviour of the animation is strange. Here is the code :

Coin.h : (UIView class)

```
@property (retain) NSArray * imagesCoinEclate;
```

I read in some tutorials that the error could come from no-retain statu of my variable, so I put it in retain

Coin.m :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

CGImageRef imageToSplitEclate = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Coin_Anim2_Spritesheet4x4_110x100.png"].CGImage;

    int x2 = 300;
    int y2 = 0;
    CGImageRef partOfImgEclate1 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToSplitEclate, CGRectMake(x2, y2, 100, 110));
    UIImage *imgEclate1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfImgEclate1];
    CGImageRelease(partOfImgEclate1);

    ...

    x2 = 0;
    y2 = 330;
    CGImageRef partOfImgEclate16 = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageToSplitEclate, CGRectMake(x2, y2, 100, 110));
    UIImage *imgEclate16 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:partOfImgEclate16];
    CGImageRelease(partOfImgEclate16);

    _imagesCoinEclate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgEclate1,imgEclate2,imgEclate3,imgEclate4,imgEclate5,imgEclate6,imgEclate7,imgEclate8,imgEclate9,imgEclate10,imgEclate11,imgEclate12,imgEclate13,imgEclate14,imgEclate15,imgEclate16, nil];

 }
    return self;
}
```

And this array is called in a method :

```
-(void)AnimationCoinExplose:(UIImageView *)imageViewCoin withCurrentX:(float)current
{
    [imageViewCoin stopAnimating];
    CGPoint centerCoin;
    centerCoin.x = currentX;
    centerCoin.y = imageViewCoin.center.y - ((imageViewCoin.frame.size.height)/2);
    UIImageView * Explode = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentX + imageViewCoin.center.x, centerCoin.y, imageViewCoin.frame.size.width + 10, imageViewCoin.frame.size.height + 10)];
     //NSLog(@"CurrentX : %f\nX : %f\nY : %f\nX size : %f\nY size : %f", currentX, currentX + imageViewCoin.center.x, centerCoin.y, imageViewCoin.frame.size.width + 10, imageViewCoin.frame.size.height + 10);
    imageViewCoin.alpha = 0.0f;
    [Explode setAnimationImages:_imagesCoinEclate];
    [Explode setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [Explode setAnimationDuration:(1/24)];
    [Explode startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:Explode];
    [Explode release];
    _IntersectionCheck = -1;
}
```

This method is called in a UIViewController, and initialize previously like this :

```
View = [[Coin alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:View];
```

And use with the accelerometer like this :

```
if (View.IntersectionCheck == -1)
    {
        if (Test.alpha == 1.0f)
        {
            [View CoinIntersection:Test becausePigX:current.x andPigY:current.y];
        }
        if (Test2.alpha == 1.0f)
        {
            [View CoinIntersection:Test2 becausePigX:current.x andPigY:current.y];
        }
    }
    else if (View.IntersectionCheck == 0)
    {

}
```

When i put all the code from Coin.m into the method

```
-(void)AnimationCoinExplose:(UIImageView *)imageViewCoin withCurrentX:(float)current
```

it's perfectly work, but not when it's in init.
The error is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1)" and in debug console "Nsarray summary unavailable"

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Rob Nah, `init` calls `initWithFrame:CGRectZero`.

Comment: Even if I put View = [[Coin alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)]; didn't change anything. I called another animation in the init part and she's working.

Comment: @H2CO3 I didn't know the default `init` called `initWithFrame`. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob You're welcome. :) Benefits of not using IB, you see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read in some tutorials that the error could come from no-retain statu of my variable, so I put it in retain

That's correct, it's just that you're not doing the assignment right.

```
_imagesCoinEclate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgEclate1, ..., nil];
```

This assigns to the instance variable directly, circumventing the setter method, so the autoreleased instance you create is not retained (the setter would do that), and it's deallocated prematurely. Use the property setter instead and don't expect magic where it isn't:

```
self.imagesCoinEclate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imgEclate1, ..., nil];
```

Or, if you wish to use the ivar directly, assign an allocated-initialized object to it, and avoid autoreleasing:

```
_imagesCointEclate = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:imgEclate1, ..., nil];
```

By the way, you ***should*** refactor the creation of those 16 objects. It's horrible.

Comment: No, the only place you should not use the setter accessor methods in `init` and `dealloc` methods. See [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Comment: @Rob I disagree with that.

Comment: Works correctly !!! Thanks =) Will accept your answer when's possible =) What would you mean by refract those 16 objetcs ?

Comment: @user2057209 You should, for example, put those objects in an array, create them in a loop, use some formula to calculate their frames, etc.

Comment: Ok, but you means when allocate to not rewrite all the code for the 16 ? It's not about dealloc them that you talk no ? Sorry i'm not english so it's not easy sometimes :(

Comment: By the way, I still disagree with the suggestion that you should use the setter in the `init` method. You should always use the ivars. But the problem in the code is that he's setting his ivar to an autoreleased object. So, instead of `_imagesCoinEclate = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];` he should use `_imagesCoinEclate = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];`, which returns a +1 retain count object.

Comment: @user2057209 I'm not English either. I'm talking about the allocation and initialization of those 16 `partOfImgEclateXXX` variables. You should avoid code repetition by refactoring their initialization into one, parametrizable block of code.

Comment: Ok i understand what you means. I should.

Comment: @Rob Updated with that - but wait. Properties are there for a reason, and I have read the arguments against them in that article, of course, but I cannot possibly agree with them. It's rare that there are **so much** race conditions coming together. If it happens, one has to pay attention and avoid using the properties, but that's like 1% of the overall cases.

Comment: In practice, I agree that it's rare that use of setter will be problematic. I believe the problems only manifest themselves when you do KVO and/or custom setters. But it strikes me as one of those guidelines that shouldn't be accepted as gospel, but rather merely as a recognition that you can avoid any unintended consequences if you always use the ivar.

Comment: @Rob Well, that's right... But it's still ugly, isn't it. (Basically it's like a fat man choosing the narrower gate instead of the wider one when trying to get into his house.)